# Xamarin Android non-static ListView example

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I'm having a difficult time creating a ListView using a custom class and a custom layout to visualise data. Creating a custom Adapter extending BaseAdapter doesn't seem to be capable of being updated with new data, and I haven't found any examples of using a custom ArrayAdapter that isn't based around simple data types. Any suggestions what should I do?

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you call notifyDataSetChanged() on BaseAdapter, there should be no problem updating your custom views with new data. I have used ListViews and RecyclerViews with custom views no problem using custom adapters.